# Video Editor where I can hold a button while playing to select sections for removal

Tags: video, audio, video-editing

I made 40GB of bad video recordings. Now I need to remove the bad parts without wasting too much time. Is there a video editor, preferably free, where I can hold a button while the video is playing and automatically mark that section as something to keep or delete from the video?

Comment: What format is the video in?  AVI,MPG,MP4, or etc?

Comment: @cybernard MP4 right out of smart phone

Answer (score 2):

https://kdenlive.org/

http://www.openshot.org/download/
Keyboard shortcuts here:
http://openshotusers.com/help/1.4/en/ar01s05.html

They are free and you should be able to do what you want.  I don't know if you will consider them simple.

VideoRedo is simple but costs money.
http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm
www.videoredo.net/helpdocs/en/plus/pdf/PlusHelp.pdf

Read pages 12-15 for keyboard shortcuts.
If you need to trim the beginning simply find the end mark it, and hit cut.
Otherwise, mark the beginning then mark the end, and then click cut.
When you are done cutting just save it in the original format and your done.

Comment: kden is linux only?

Comment: How exactly would I be able to do it? The hotkeys for example.